# Open a view in an html file with url parameters

Tags: javascript, php, html, model-view-controller, web

I am trying to create an MVC web app, without any MVC framework. What I've done is to make an index.html with a section were all the views are loaded, when a user wants them. This though creates the problem that when a user types a direct url like: www.foo.com/bar - it doesn't point him to the view bar. I know how to point the user to a webpage with a router file, but I don't know how to do it, when the view is only a part of a page and it is opened in another page. Can I do this with the router, or how can this be done?

For clarity I am running php on the server side and I use AJAX calls to get the views.

Comment: Code! Code!! Code!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the detail pages do not have a real page server side you need a server side component that rewrites the URLS to a frontcontroller page  that loads the index.html and that bootstraps that page with the correct view.

I suggest to take a look at the mini PHP  frontcontroller component [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/)

If you do not want to use such a component you can always do this using something like apache rewrite rules and your own PHP landing page. This is rather simple for smaller MVC websites. If you're going to build a bigger one I suggest to pick a few smaller frameworks that each do one thing well. I have done this using Silex and Twig on the server side and jQuery and Knockout on the client side.

Comment: I would appreciate a way to do it manually, but this works, so thanks!